# Declaring an array of a class as a private member of that class?

Tags: c++, tree

I have this tree I'm trying to work with.. I have it currently as

```
class TRIE {
char letter;
int isWord;
TRIE *children [MAX_CHILDREN];  
};
```

what I'm confused about is declaring an array of the same type within the class.. will this work? Or how do I change it to make it correct? (it's a tree type of class.. so the array will be filled with children nodes)

Comment: You can declare the array of POINTERS to the class just fine.  Declaring an array of the class would cause universe to implode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This will work. Since you are declaring a array of pointers to TRIE.

Answer (score 1):

yes. it works.

```
....    
TRIE *children [MAX_CHILDREN];
....
```

actually you place an array of address of objects(might be created later) of type "TRIE" or subclass of "TRIE"